# Fragment loses cursor data on orientation change

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with two pages: PageOne, PageTwo. PageTwo is a Fragment that contains a ListView, which I populate using a CursorAdapter. The CursorAdapter is filled by a LoaderManager `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`. When I change the orientation of the device, PageTwo loses its content. What's a simple way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a Bundle to perfom this.

In onCreate method :

```
 if (savedInstanceState != null) {
       mNumber = savedInstanceState.getInt(POSITION);
  }
```

in the onSaveInstranceState method (you need to override it)

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putInt(POSITION, mNumber);
}
```